# Getting 2x2 individual table by Department

Tags: r, probability, data-modeling

My problem is to analyze the data set 'UCBAmissions' in R. My function takes a 2 by 2 table and analyzing it. I have already make analysis on the data aggregated over departments with the following code: `apply(UCBAdmissions,c(1,2), sum)`. My attempt is to have multiple 2 by 2 tables with aggregated over individual departments: A,B,C,D,E,F. How can I make or sort the data to have individual aggregated tables.

```
#I have tried using sweep in 'R' by my hint. Here is my code: 

sweep(UCBAdmissions,c(2,3),apply(UCBAdmissions,c(2,3),sum),"/")
#I just don't want this to be prob.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for base `asplit` and `list2env` functions to split the array by its 3-rd dimension into individual tables in the Global environment:

```
 A <- asplit(UCBAdmissions, 3)
```

Output:

```
> A
$A
          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  512     89
  Rejected  313     19

$B
          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  353     17
  Rejected  207      8

$C
          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  120    202
  Rejected  205    391

$D
          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  138    131
  Rejected  279    244

$E
          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted   53     94
  Rejected  138    299

$F
          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted   22     24
  Rejected  351    317
```

One more step to get individual tables:

```
list2env(A,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

To show a table created in the Global environment:

```
> B
          Gender
Admit      Male Female
  Admitted  353     17
  Rejected  207      8
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just want to clarify for what I did. I use this code `Table = sweep(UCBAdmissions, c(2,3),c(1,2,3,4,5,6), "+")`. However the entries for each department is added by 2 units. I don't know why this could happen!!!

Comment: Do you insist on using `sweep` only to solve this problem?  Let me know if my answer solves your problem. And if it does, please accept it. Tx)

Comment: Yes, my question insists on using `sweep` only to solve this problem. I see what you did; however, It is new to me using `asplit`.

Comment: I am confused then. What do you mean by "My attempt is to have multiple 2 by 2 tables with aggregated over individual departments: A,B,C,D,E,F. How can I make or sort the data to have individual aggregated tables.". Individual tables are already aggregated numbers per department, aren't they? If so then what else do you want to aggregate and what data you want to make or sort? Can you give me your desired output format and tell me why sweep is the only solution? Thanks.